# Bootstrap not happening - Push Right block Div above Left Block on responsive small device

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a Bootstrap theme. I have a product page where there is Left and Right block div. Trying to push the right block div above the left block when the screen resizes. Please see i have done the following code updates and changes, however i'm not getting the actual result.

Original: [Check the actual website here](http://45.55.39.151/magento/porto/index.php/demo11_en/wooden-chair.html)

```
<div class="col-main col-sm-9">
LEFT BLOCK
</div>

<div class="col-right sidebar col-sm-3">
RIGHT BLOCK
</div>
```

Update:

```
<div class="col-main col-sm-9 col-sm-push-3 col-md-push-0">
LEFT BLOCK
</div>

<div class="col-right sidebar col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-9 col-md-pull-0">
RIGHT BLOCK
</div>
```

What i expect on small device when responsive:

```
<div class="col-right sidebar col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-9 col-md-pull-0">
RIGHT BLOCK
</div>
<div class="col-main col-sm-9 col-sm-push-3 col-md-push-0">
LEFT BLOCK
</div>
```

Anyone know why the Right block doesn't stack above the Left Div when the screen resizes? This theme uses Bootstrap 3+. Column ordering should work in Bootstrap right?

Thanks, need some inputs, i'm still trying my hands on CSS.

Comment: Please avoid updating your code after posting it, unless it's a mistake or fatal error. It can make it harder to debug, and invalidate previous solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this [sample](http://www.bootply.com/93614#):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-4">Menu</div>
<div class="col-xs-8">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8">Right Content</div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-4">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try this. I'll remove the Menu div, as my layout don't need one. I'll let you know if it works

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-6">
      LEFT BLOCK
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
      RIGHT BLOCK
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Do you need something like this? If so just `col-xs-6` is more than enough.

Comment: Thank you, when i tried col-xs-6 on the Left and Right block div, they are stacking up horizontally on small screen which is quite ok and i might even settle for it if i don't find any solution now. Can you check this link to my theme here: http://45.55.39.151/magento/porto/index.php/demo11_en/wooden-chair.html , is there any way to stack up the Right block above the left block on small screen ? Thanks again.

Comment: Please do a vote if this code worked, and you are talking about which part in the shared link ? http://45.55.39.151/magento/porto/index.php/demo11_en/wooden-chair.html

Comment: This is the part: <div class="main-container col2-right-layout"> Left Block Div | RIGHT Block Div</div>

Comment: @tryfullstack, it is looking fine.

Comment: Right, its looking, also i just wanna move the right block div above the left block on small screen (ie. when viewed from mobile device)